# PHP GD imagecopyresampled horrible quality

Tags: php, image, copy, gd

Not sure why it looks so bad, but when I copy an image over another image, it looks extremely terrible, like it lost almost all its colors for some reason.

```
$img = imagecreate(240, 140);    
$wall = imagecreatefrompng($src);
imagecopyresampled($img, $wall, 0, 0, 40, 340, 240, 140, 240, 140);
```

I've been trying to find a solution myself but I can't seem to find one, anybody really good with GD that can help? I can't use imagemagick.

Comment: _imagecreate — Create a new palette based image_... means image can have a maximum of 256 colors, probably the reason why your image looks washed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create your canvas image with [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) rather than [`imagecreate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) as the former creates a palette based canvas with limited colour support.

I presume you are then using [`imagepng()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to save our output the image. The third argument accepted by this function defines the quality of the image, or the compression level (0-9)

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't figure this out, must be a lack of sleep...